# Does Python guarantee that a coroutine will run to its first waiting-point immediately?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

If I have three asynchronous methods:

```
async def f():
    doSomething1()
    await g()

async def g():
    doSomething2()
    await h()

async def h():
    # some unspecified content
```

Does Python provide any guarantees that no other coroutines can be executed on the current thread between the calls to `doSomething1()` and `doSomething2()`?

Answer (score 1):

> Does Python provide any guarantees that no other coroutines can be
> executed on the current thread between the calls to doSomething1() and
> doSomething2()?

Short Answer:
When the execution reaches the line `doSomething1()`, first `doSomething1()` is executed, then `g()`'s body, which in turn means then `doSomething2()`. It's guaranteed.

---

Let's think about it this way: Assuming your application is running with asyncio's eventloop, How can Asyncio execute another Task? Only when a Task yields the control to the event loop. When does it happen? When the execution reaches the `yield` keyword. (I didn't say `await` keyword because it's not true)

If the execution reaches the line `doSomething1()`, it calls `doSomething1`. It can be either a normal function or another coroutine. If it's a coroutine it basically does nothing(except creating a coroutine object) since we didn't `await` it. If it's a normal function it will execute. While executing, it *can* register other Tasks on the event loop BUT they won't run until we let them to run!

Now execution reaches the `await g()`, here `f` coroutine is blocked until we get result back from `g()`. After the coroutine is created by calling `g`, its body gets executed immediately, so the `doSomething2` is executed(the story is the same as `doSomething1`). You see, NO ONE yields anything to the event loop yet.

So in your case, if `doSomething1()` is executed, `g`'s body executes immediately and `doSomething2()` gets execute immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. In most cases `doSomething2()` will be the next thing executed, but don't rely on it.  And it's sloppy programming.

Calling `g()` causes the execution of the coroutine `g` to be added to the event loop. You then call await, which returns control back to the event loop.

If `g` happens to be the only thing waiting to execute, then it will certainly be executed next.  If there are multiple coroutines/tasks waiting execution (e.g. this is part of some larger program), then any of them might run next.

Comment: "*Calling g() causes the execution of the coroutine g to be added to the event loop.*" No. we didn't create task, it's a coroutine. It will not be registered on the event loop.

Comment: @S.B You're right.  My wording was a little bit imprecise, but I wanted to get the point across that g() doesn't start running immediately. Can you help me with a better way of wording it?

Comment: Actually `g()` *does* start running immediately.

Answer (score 0):

No.

That's cause asynchonous execution allows for interleaving of tasks and other coroutines can be executed while a task is waiting for an "await" statement to complete.

I think this content may help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Yes it's how asynchronous works generally but in the OP's case there is no opportunity for other arbitrary tasks to get executed. The execution order is `Something1()` then `g()`'s body - which means `Something2()`.